# Javascript show/hide and ahref

Tags: javascript, href

I have a show/hide function on my main content on my home page, for some reason when clicking on the internal href links it closes the div instead of links to directed page.

Any idea?

http://www.richardsimon.co/

Comment: You should paste your code where the onclick event is set. IMO you put it on the wrong container

Comment: Which part are you talking about . Give name of a link

Comment: I have the onclick event on the image which triggers the div to open/close and all the href are placed as needed on the text I need linking

Comment: <div class="columns different"><a href="javascript:unhide('welcome');"><img class="scale-with-grid" src="http://www.richardsimon.co/wp-content/themes/incipiens/images/different.png" /></a>
        </div>